# Compressing CSS with no spaces via PHP?

Tags: php, css, compression

Wondering how to reach a css file like this one from css-tricks.com

http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-9/style.css?v=9.5

Not sure if he is using php to accomplish this or not. I've been reading countless articles with no luck.

Also, is it something automated that spits out the version number after the .css? Been seeing it around and wondered how to achieve a clean css file.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html So it has nothing to do with php. "Also, is it something automated that spits out the version number after the .css?" --- yep, I'm sure it is done on build step

Comment: as @zerkms noted, there are libraries which do this. As you can imagine, there are lots of different "levels" of compression - eg if your server knows what changes are made to the CSS, you can change Ids /class names to be shorter - but only if the html is also changed to use the shorter names. Failing that, there's removal of whitespace, etc... it depends how complex you want to get

Answer (score 2):

It's simple enough to use an editor with Search/Replace and strip out all the unnecessary spaces. For instance, when I write CSS I only use spaces to separate keywords - I use newlines and tabs to format it legibly. So I could just replace all tabs and newlines with the empty string and the result is "minified" CSS like the one above.

The version number is a fairly common cache trick. It doesn't affect anything server-side, but the browser sees it as a new file, and caches it as such. This makes it easy to purge the cache of all users when an update is made. Personally, though, I use a PHP function to append `"?t=".filemtime($file)` (in other words, the timestamp that the file was modified) automatically, which saves me the trouble of manually updating version numbers.

---

Here is the exact code I use to automatically append modification time to JS and CSS files:

```
<?php
ob_start(function($data) {
    chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "(/(?:js|css)/.*?\.(?:js|css))",
                     // all the relevant files are in /js and /css folders of the root
        function($m) {
           if( file_exists(substr($m[0],1)))
               return $m[0]."?t=".filemtime(substr($m[0],1));
           else return $m[0];
        },
        $data
    );
});
?>
```

Comment: +1 Nice trick on the file time. I use current time to prevent caching but hadn't considered file time.

Comment: Just a note that you can't remove all spaces: some selectors need spaces in their parameters. I mention this merely for completeness.

Comment: @Basic filemtime allows the CSS to be cached, so you can send out cache headers with it to cache it forever (read: for a year or whatever). Then when you modify it it will automatically invalidate.

Comment: Thanks @ascii-lime, I got that - And to be fair, the server _should_ be configured to send the appropriate headers anyway but I just thought it was a nice compromise between no timestamp (relying on server, not portable) and `now` (no caching, inefficient)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid to do it manually because you may corrupt your css.
There are good tools available which will solve such problems for you without to be tricky.

An excellent solution is [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) which is an assets manager and allow you to filter (minify, compress) using various tools (yuicompressor, google closure, etc..).

It is currently bundle by default with Symfony2 but may be used standalone in any PHP Project. 
I've successfully implemented it in a Zend Framework project.